# ps aux | grep result depends on terminal size on FreeBSD

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd

From experimenting, it seems that even when using `ps aux | grep ...` the output depends on the terminal size. This seems seriously weird for me.

Isn't a pipe supposed to make command's output behave in a predictable way?

For example `ls` does all fancy formatting magic when run on its own, but when run like `ls | less` it always returns the same output styling.

But unlike ls, the output from `ps aux | less` cuts the lines to terminal width on FreeBSD (on bash at least). From my brief experimenting, the same command always outputs full length lines in Linux when used with pipes.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Is this just a really weird FreeBSD default? From my understanding this "feature" would make it almost impossible to write reliable bash scripts on FreeBSD as the output of simple piped commands would not be reliable. Isn't this a problem?

Update:
Thanks to Bert, I've tried it with `ps aux > somefile` and the **lines inside the file are cut** exactly like how it was with grep and less!

Info:
FreeBSD 10.2, bash 4.3.42, same when connecting over SSH or when logged in locally via KVM.

Comment: I'm on `bash` and `ls` and/or `ps aux` produce same output with or without `|`, why don't you post these examples to question and also post output from `alias` command as well and version of your FreeBSD, bash and whatever else is relevant...

Comment: I've added the relevant information. There is only difference if you have long lines (longer than your terminal's width) on ps aux for example. You can try by making your terminal narrower.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this issue. Can you add some example commands and the output you are getting?

Comment: It sounds that your system has a broken implementation of `ps` that incorrectly honors terminal width always. My system has `ps --version` saying `procps-ng version 3.3.10` and at least this version seems to have sane behavior (lines are cut when output goes directly to terminal, lines are not cut when output goes to anywhere else).

Answer (score 1):

**It's not the piping doing it**. Part of your problem is your pager, `less`. By default it truncates at the same length as your terminal does. You can fix this by telling it not to do that:

`ps aux | less -S`

`ps` detects the window width and outputs to fit

The [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) has one way to bypass this:

> -w Use 132 columns to display information, instead of the default which is your window size. If the -w option is specified more than
>   once, ps will use as many columns as necessary without regard for your
>   window size. Note that this option has no effect if the “command”
>   column is not the last column displayed.

Another solution would be to pipe the output to a file

`ps aux > somefile`

Comment: @zsero is saying that the trick of redirecting stdout does not work on his setup, so you're not really addressing the question here. His setup is a bit bizarre though, could do with some more examples to narrow down the circumstance in which this can happen.

Comment: 1. It doesn't depend on less, it is the same with grep.
2. It is actually the same when piping to a file. `ps aux > somefile` has the lines cut exactly at terminal length!

Comment: Actually the reverse: `less` defaults to wrapping long lines and `-S` makes it truncate. But 'procps' `ps` on (all?) Linux does widen when output is redirected (including pipe) while FreeBSD `ps` needs `w` -- or envvar COLUMNS.